# Is it possible to use MERGE statement to update a table in Azure using local db?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table in a remote server that I want to update/delete based on the data I already have in a local server. My thought is to use MERGE for this. but SQL give me Invalid object name error if I use any remote server name.
So is this possible? any advice is welcomed!

Comment: To my knowledge, `merge` statement acts as `upsert`, so it inserts or updates depending the joining criteria, but not deletes. What's your query?

Comment: I can deal with the delete condition within the server but my concern right now is with the upsert and using merge to connect to remote server which I'm not able to do.

Comment: You can use data factory to Copy and Merge data from local db to Azure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a dataset to your local DB via self-host intergration runtime。
   [image]
2. Then create the table,table type parameter and a procudure in Azure SQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EmpType] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [age] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmp]

@emp [dbo].[EmpType] READONLY

AS
        MERGE [dbo].[emp] AS target_sqldb

        USING @emp AS source_tblstg

        ON target_sqldb.id = source_tblstg.id 

        WHEN MATCHED THEN

        UPDATE SET

        target_sqldb.name = source_tblstg.name,

        target_sqldb.age = source_tblstg.age
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 

        INSERT VALUES (

            source_tblstg.id,

            source_tblstg.name,

            source_tblstg.age
        );

        --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        --DELETE;
```

3. Select stored procedure and import table tpye parameter at sink setting.
   [image]